# Why would I want to cast a matlab enumeration to int32?

Tags: matlab, casting, enumeration

Today i stepped into this code snippet:

```matlab
classdef (Enumeration,Sealed) ClassBlabla < int8
    enumeration
        ALPHA(0)
        BETA(1)
        GAMMA(2)
    end

    methods (static)
        function ret = doSomething()
            ret = containers.Map(.......)
            for i = int32(ClassBlabla.ALPHA):int32(ClassBlabla.GAMMA)
                ret(i) = somethingelse(blablabla(i))
            end
         end
    end
end
```

What is that int32(...) in the for?? A cast? Why do I want to cast to int32? Isn't ALPHA already 0 and GAMMA already 2??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to widen the ALPHA and GAMMA values fro `int8` to `int32`. Most likely, that's because either the `blablabla()` function expects an `int32` input, or the `ret` value is expected to have `int32` keys. ALPHA and GAMMA are already 0 and 2, but they are `int8` instead of `int32`, and `blablabla()` or clients of `doSomething()` may not play well with `int8` values. (You can tell ALPHA and GAMMA are `int8` because of the `ClasBlabla < int8` at the top.)